# $\limsup_{k\rightarrow\infty}X_k/k$ for identically distributed random variables $X_k$.

Tags: probability, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Let $\{X_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of identically distributed and not independent random variables on the natural numbers. I am interested in conditions that would ensure that almost surely
$$
\limsup_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{X_k}{k} < \infty.
$$
One such a condition is $\mathbb{E}(X_k)<\infty$, since then
$$
\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}P(X_k\ge k) = \mathbb{E}(X_k)<\infty.
$$
Borel-Cantelli then gives $P(\limsup_{k\rightarrow\infty}\{\omega\in\Omega\mid\ X_k\ge k\}) = 0$, which means that for each $\omega$ there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $X_k<k$ for all $k\ge N$. Therefore we get that $\limsup_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{X_k}{k}\le 1$.

The random variables I have to deal with are quite complex and thus I am interested in a less strict condition that ensures the finite limit superior.

Thank you in advance!

---

EDIT

My thoughts on extended conditions. In the expectation proof and the answer given we look for an $r$ such that $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}P(X_k>rk)<\infty$. I will try to explore whether some random variable replacing $r$ helps, since we dont need the limit superior to be equal for all $\omega$, just finite.

Comment: The question specifically asks for the non independent case and you accept an answer assuming crucially (although the necessity seems unclear to its OP) independence?

Comment: To be honest, I have never read the guidelines. Usually when I don't get a new answer for a couple of days I tend to accept the best one from the ones given as a token of aprreciation for the effort done, even if this answer is not optimal. Is it better to leave the question open indefinitely?

Comment: Is this a nice example of false dichotomy or what?

Comment: Good point. I will leave quesions open for a longer period of time in the future:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just saw your comment; note here I'm assuming the $X_k$ are independent. Relevant or not, seems interesting.

The following seems like it must be wrong, can't be that simple. But I don't see where the error is. Suppose $X_k\ge0$. Seems to me that if $\Bbb E[X_k]<\infty$ then $\limsup X_k/k=0$ almost surely, while if $\Bbb E[X_k]=\infty$ then $\limsup X_k/k=\infty$ almost surely.

First, if $\Bbb E[X_k]<\infty$: You've shown that $\limsup X_k/k\le 1$ almost surely. The same applies to $NX_k$ for any positive integer $N$, so that $\limsup X_k/k\le1/N$ almost surely, hence $\limsup X_k/k=0$ almost surely.

On the other hand, note that for $X\ge0$ we have $\Bbb E[X]<\infty$ if and only if $\sum P(X\ge k)<\infty$, regardless of whether $X$ is integer-valued. So if the $X_k\ge 0$ are iid and $\Bbb E[X_k]=\infty $ then Borel-Cantelli shows that $\limsup X_k/k\ge1$ almost surely, and again applying this to $cX_k$ shows that in fact $\limsup X_k/k=\infty$ almost surely.

**Edit:** Maybe this actually is right! I didn't see how at first, but in fact it's equivalent to the condition that Robert Israel gave in the answer he deleted on grounds of irrelevance. Saying $\sum\ln F(rk)>-\infty$ for some $r>0$ is the same as $\sum \ln F(k)>-\infty$, by monotonicity. Since $F(k)\to1$ from below this is the same as $\sum(1-F(k))<\infty$, which is the same as $\sum P(X_k\ge k)<\infty$.

Comment: Yes: in the case where $X_k$ are independent, $\mathbb E[X_k] < \infty$ is necessary and sufficient.  With dependent $X_k$, this is no longer necessary, e.g. in the extreme case all $X_k = X_1$, $X_k/k \to 0$ whenever $X_1 \ne +\infty$.  Of course, the fact that $\mathbb E[X_k] < \infty$ is necessary in the independent case means that you'll have some trouble finding a less restrictive condition for the general case.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks for the, erm, proof verification - seemed like something I'd have seen before if true. (Yes, I'd thought of that extreme case, hence the difficulty in formulating a more general condition...)

Comment: Thank you very much for the insights. Observing they are equivalent under independence could be very helpful.